# Creating a large sprite with ImageMagick via PHP Consumes 100% CPU

Tags: php, imagemagick, sprite, cpu-usage

So I've this:

```
exec("cd $upload_directory && convert \\( +append -limit memory 1 -limit map 1 *.jpg \\) -strip -trim -interlace Plane -quality 60 output.jpg
```

The workflow is:

- User uploads *.zip file, containing about 30 pictures 2048x1152 each
- Application unzips zip file
- Application takes the pictures and makes a large sprite out of all of them
- Application then redirects to a different page for processing.

Now the problems is with making the large sprite. It consumes 100% CPU (according to `top` on the server), it fails when there are many images. Also the process outputs `Killed` without any further error message.

Now, I'm sure I can solve this by throwing more muscle on the server, but I'm having the feeling that the one I have isn't the most efficient.

What can I try to mitigate the problem?

Comment: When you top it, can you see the memory consumption for that convert process? It looks like you are making a REALLY large image there..  2048*1152*30*2 (if it is 16bit )= 135MB. That would be the minimal memory requirement before adding any layers..

Comment: Looks like the process is going over its CPU or memory limit. What's the status code? (If you don't know how to get it in PHP, add `; echo $?` at the end of the shell script.)

Comment: @MoeTsao: How is that possible? All the images combined weigh less than 10MB

Comment: @Gilles: Status code is `1`.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha They weigh less than 10MB when *compressed*. ImageMagick is probably decompressing them to work with them. And I'd guess 32-bit, not 16-bit, so twice Moe's calculated size.

Comment: @Madara That is a JPG output right? When convert work on the image it will need it to be in something similar to BMP. That is not compressed and is huge. Reconsider your workflow to treat your server better, or offload it to a dedicated beefy server to do this..

Comment: @MoeTsao: Hmmm, so how "beefy" do I need to get? Anything above 135? Or will it face other difficulties for some other reason if I go for, say, 256?

Comment: You may want to do some test to find out. I won't know it. How frequent is this function called? How much Ram do you see it consumed before it quit? How much CPU? Do some benchmark with command line first before moving to finalizing the script and ordering the hardware. However, I still thinks that changing the workflow may be the way to go. What is the purpose of having a Gigapixel sprite? Is there any other more efficient way to achieve that goal?

Comment: @MoeTsao: Once in a while, never simultaneously. Almost all of it, leaving approx 500k, All of it, reaching 100%. Also, the purpose is to make something similar to [this](truview.ortery.com/HTMLJavaScript/Nike_PegususTV/HTML5Viewer.html) on a larger scale. If you can suggest a better way, I'm open to ideas.

Comment: A really quick search gave me this: `http://js360viewer.com/` This does not require the image to be one big sprite.. Maybe look into this direction? Or what other JS library that would allow zoom + rotate?

Comment: @MoeTsao Besides that possible solution you posted I am curios what is happening behind the scenes. When I run that conversion task for madara and keeping an eye on the mem consumption it is minimal (the conversion works on my machine though with better specs). Does the OS also kill processes based on somewhat heavy load normal cpu usage ?

Comment: Did you run it from shell? or through PHP?  PHP has timeout, which you may want to raise it with ini setting. If it is from shell then throw some -v or debug flag so you can see what it is doing and where did it bug out.  But I want to restate this.. Trying to send 10M Jpg over the net is not very kind to even slower DSL. let along mobile or dialup. Rethink how to avoid stitching image may be what needs to be done here.

Comment: @MoeTsao: A timeout raises an error. Don't worry, I can debug PHP well enough myself, it's not a problem with PHP (as evidence, even when I run it from shell it happens). Also, sending a 10M jpg over the net is kinder than sending 30 ~500kb pictures.

Comment: Then try to add '-debug' to the convert command and see what went wrong?

Comment: @MoeTsao: It's most certainly the RAM. I've looked at OOM and it's killing it every time. I'm currently looking at alternatives, or possibly to raise the RAM limitation. Thank you so much for your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You kind-of answered your own question. You are doing something really intensive. The expected outcome is that CPU usage will shoot-up. Unzipping takes memory and cpu. Creating massive images takes IO, CPU, and Memory. If you ever used Photoshop, youll notice that your systems memory and cpu always shoots-up. Dealing with images is no simple task.

If you want to handle large images using the current method, then you need a stronger server. There is no magic parameter that will make the process use less memory. If you have a 32MB image, its going to take a lot of memory to read it before you can even try to reduce its size.

Hope that helps!